# About convert Image to byte[] and reverse in Java

Tags: java, image, arrays

i have one problem when i convert image to byte[] and reverse:

I have 2 function convert image to byte[] as follow

```
public byte[] extractBytes2 (String ImageName) throws IOException {
    File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);
    WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage .getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();    
    return ( data.getData() );
}
```

and

```
public byte[] extractBytes (String ImageName) throws IOException 
{
    Path path = Paths.get(ImageName);
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    return data;
}
```

I will have byte[] byteArray

```
byteArray = extractBytes2("image/pikachu.png");
```

or

```
byteArray = extractBytes("image/pikachu.png");
```

when i convert byte[] to Image i use

```
Graphics g = panelMain.getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
        g2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, GiaoDienChinh.this);
        g2D.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        panelMain.setOpaque(true);
        panelMain.paintComponents(g2D);
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {           
    }
    finally {       
    }
```

but i only draw with byteArray use function "extractBytes" not with "extractBytes2" !!!

Anyone can explain me how i can draw image with byteArray which got from "extractByte2"?

Thanks for all support!

Comment: I actually don't understand the problem: is method `extractBytes2` not working or not called or does `byteArray` always holds the result of `extractBytes` when you paint the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the paint code.

`ImageIO.read(in)` is expecting a valid image format that one of it's pluggable service provides knows how to read and convert to a `BufferedImage`.

When you pass the byes from `extractBytes`, you're simply passing back an array of bytes that represents the actual image file.  I'd be the same as saying `Image.read(new File("image/pikachu.png"))`

However, the data buffer returned from your `extractBytes2` is returning a internal representation of the image data, which may not be "readable" by `ImageIO`.

**UPDATED**

> A BufferedImage is an accessible buffer of image data, essentially
>   pixels, and their RGB colors. The BufferedImage provides a powerful
>   way to manipulate the Image data. A BufferedImage object is made up of
>   two parts a ColorModel object and a Raster object.

[image]

*Referenced from [here](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/ultimate-image/)*

**UPDATED**

I had this wacky idea on the way home of how to convert a `BufferedImage` to a byte array...

The basic idea is to use `ImageIO.write` to write out the `BufferedImage` to a `ByteOutputStream`...

```
public static byte[] extractBytes2(String ImageName) throws IOException {
    File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

    ByteOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        bos = new ByteOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", bos);
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return bos == null ? null : bos.getBytes();

}
```

Here's my test...

[image]

```
public class TestByteImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestByteImage();
    }

    public static byte[] extractBytes2(String ImageName) throws IOException {
        File imgPath = new File(ImageName);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);

        ByteOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", bos);
        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        return bos == null ? null : bos.getBytes();

    }

    public TestByteImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ImagePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage original;
        private byte[] byteData;
        private BufferedImage fromBytes;

        public ImagePane() {
            String name = "/path/to/your/image";
            try {
                original = ImageIO.read(new File(name));
                byteData = extractBytes2(name);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48f));

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return original == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(original.getWidth() * 2, original.getHeight());
        }

        protected void drawText(Graphics2D g2d, String text, int x, int width) {
            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D tmpg = img.createGraphics();
            tmpg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            tmpg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            tmpg.setFont(g2d.getFont());
            tmpg.setColor(Color.RED);
            FontMetrics fm = tmpg.getFontMetrics();
            int xPos = ((width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2);
            int yPos = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            tmpg.drawString(text, xPos, yPos);
            tmpg.dispose();

            AffineTransform transform = g2d.getTransform();
            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(-10), x + (x + width) / 2, getHeight() / 2));
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, 0, this);
            g2d.setTransform(transform);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (original != null) {
                g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, this);
                drawText((Graphics2D) g, "Original", 0, original.getWidth());
            }
            if (byteData != null && fromBytes == null) {
                try {
                    fromBytes = ImageIO.read(new ByteInputStream(byteData, byteData.length));
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (fromBytes != null) {
                g.drawImage(fromBytes, getWidth() - fromBytes.getWidth(), 0, this);
                drawText((Graphics2D) g, "From Bytes", getWidth() - fromBytes.getWidth(), fromBytes.getWidth());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i see. But have any way i can use byteArray from `extractBytes2` to draw image?

Answer (score 2):

Use ImageIo to write bufferedImage into ByteArrayOutputStream, then invoke the toByteArray method of the stream.[image: BufferedImage to ByteArray]