# 24 bit RGB image to 8 bit gray scale byte array

Tags: java, image-processing

I am looking for some code snippet to convert a 24 bit RGB image to 8 bit gray scale byte array in Java. I have explored on the net but not able to find any relevant material.

Suppose we have a 24 bit RGB image ("C:\img\face.jpg") and we need to convert it into 8 bit gray scale byte array something like byte[] face in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `byte` array is suppose to contain the pixel data...

Comment: [Example of a gray scale converstion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899824/java-convert-a-greyscale-and-sepia-version-of-an-image-with-bufferedimage/21900125#21900125)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to image processing. I just want to do following
1. jpeg image into raw rgb pixel data
2. convert raw rgb pixel data to grayscale pixel data
3. final output will be grayscale pixel data

Answer (score 1):

In a "very" simply way you could do something like...

```
    try {
        BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/img/face.jpg"));
        BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g2d = gray.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(source, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
        ImageIO.write(gray, "png", ios);
        ios.close();

        byte[] array = baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The byte array will contain the actual PNG image, NOT the raw pixel data, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282740/about-convert-image-to-byte-and-reverse-in-java/13283131#13283131), this is important!

You can also use something like...

```
BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
op.filter(source, gray);
```

to convert the image to gray-scale as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899824/java-convert-a-greyscale-and-sepia-version-of-an-image-with-bufferedimage/21900125#21900125)

If you literally want the pixel data, you might be able to do something like...

```
WritableRaster raster = gray.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();    
byte[] rawPixels = data.getData();
```

Comment: I want to add that averaging the R, G, B channels is not the best formula for conversion to gray. More here: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg That's nice, do you have an example in Java?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Will it works in the following manner?

1. jpeg image into raw rgb pixel data 2. convert raw rgb pixel data to grayscale pixel data 3. final output will be grayscale pixel data

Comment: It should, if you want to go that path.  Load the image and use the last example to get the raw byte/pixel data...

Comment: @MadProgrammer- like this ? --
BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\img\\facefind.jpg"));
BufferedImage gray = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
op.filter(source, gray);
WritableRaster raster = gray.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] rawPixels = data.getData();
System.out.println("BYTES---------- "+rawPixels.length+ Arrays.toString(rawPixels));

Comment: Well, if you want to take the pixel data and convert that to grayscale, then you only need to read the image and extract the pixel data. Of course to save it again, you will need to apply the pixel data to another `BufferedImage` and save that. Based on your previous comment, I don't think you the `ColorConvertOp`